# How to do a pull request from my current state

Tags: visual-studio, github, pull-request

**Steps already taken**

1. I found a github repository from user X
2. I clicked "open in visual studio"
3. I made some changes and did a commit. It committed to my local repository.
4. I installed github extension for Visual Studio 2017
5. I created a fork in my own github repository directly from user X's repository.

**Question**

I want my changes to appear as a pull request in the repository of user X.

What are the exact steps in Visual Studio (not command line) that I need to take to do that, given where I am now?

**More info**

I don't have or want any permissions in this github repository of user X. It probably involves doing a pull request from a fork. I guess what I can't seem to figure out is how to get my changes into my fork that I made. Once it's there, I think I know how to create a pull request in user X's repository from my fork. My github extension only mentions his repository and therefore I can't push my changes into my fork.

**Update: Pushing to my fork fails**

My remotes:

[image]

When I tried to push to my fork on Github:

[image]

I got this:

[image]

My fork on Github doesn't have any branches (that I own (under the "Yours" tab)). So the push fails. But I need to successfully do a push to get a branch, right? Seems like a catch 22.

Comment: I think you did it wrong way. You should start with creating fork in GutHub, then clone your fork (open in VS), then commit, push and then create pull request from your fork.

Comment: you don't have any branches in your fork? How you forked repo?

Comment: where is Yours tab?

Comment: @Alexan I went to his repo, and clicked the fork button. It created the fork in my account, with his three existing branches. So I show 3 branches but 0 branches under the "Yours" tab. I added more pictures. And I'm googling under this new error.

Comment: @Alexan, under https://github.com/toddmo/MathMLToCSharp/branches there is a Yours button which shows my branches. Maybe it's irrelevant to my issue. It's just, the error message makes it sound like there must be a branch I own to push to. I'm probably wrong about that.

Comment: I don't see this button, because I'm not owner. But probably it isn't related. What you can do, it's just replace origin with you fork and try push to origin.

Comment: just press origin | Edit and change philipshys to toddmo

Comment: @Alexan, that did it! I don't think that VS Github integration is very intuitive at all. But I appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you did it wrong way.

How contribute to GitHub repo:

1. Fork GutHub repo, you get fork of this pero in your GitHub account
2. Clone your fork (just clicking open in VS)
3. Commit into your local repo
4. Push to your fork
5. Create pull request from your fork

See [guide here](https://akrabat.com/the-beginners-guide-to-contributing-to-a-github-project/).

What you can do in your current situation:

1. Push from your local repo to your fork (you need to change remote of your local repo)
2. create pull request from fork.

or

1. Clone your fork (open in VS)
2. Merge it with you local repo, when you have commits
3. Push to your GitHub fork
4. Create pull request from fork.

How to change remote of you local repo in VS:

1. In Team Explorer tab go to Home:

[image]

2. Go to Settings:

[image]

3. Repository Settings => Remotes:

[image]

When you do push, you can choose to which remote push:

[image]

**Comment**: instead adding remotes for you local repo, you can just change origin to your fork, where you need to push.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how to do your step #1 "change remote of your local repo". What buttons do I mash to get there?

Comment: Team explorer => Home => Settings => Repository Settings => Remotes

Comment: I added my fork as a remote. What do I do next? My local repo is still pointed to user X repository's remote. (Thanks)

Comment: when you push you can choose where to push, see added picture

Comment: but actually you can just change origin of your local repo

Comment: That was good info I didn't have. If you're done working on this, I understand. I upvoted b/c of your effort. I updated my question with the failure I had trying to do the push as you described. Thanks again.