# GitHub - After 'git clone', how can I make a pull request?

Tags: git, github

I've read [this](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/). But it doesn't answer to what I've done and what I want.

I'm very new to git, and I've made a "`git clone https://github.com/qmk/qmk_firmware`"

Then I've created a new directory `layouts/community/ergodox/azerty`.
In this directory I've created those files:

- `layouts/community/ergodox/azerty/keymap.c`
- `layouts/community/ergodox/azerty/simple_visualizer.h`
- `layouts/community/ergodox/azerty/README.md`
- `layouts/community/ergodox/azerty/visualizer.c`
- `layouts/community/ergodox/azerty/rules.mk`
- `layouts/community/ergodox/azerty/config.h`

Now I'd like to make a pull request for the maintainers to merge my "community layout".

I dont know what to do.

Comment: Is your question, "Within GitHub how do I initiate a pull request?"

Comment: @jhenderson2099 Yes, I'm sorry if I'm not very precise with the term I should use...

Comment: You created a new folder (`layouts/community/ergodox/azerty`) as part of the project.  Did you create a branch?  That is, what is the name of the branch in which you made the changes?

Comment: you need fork first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How contribute to GitHub repo:

1. Fork the GitHub repo, you get the fork in your GitHub account
2. Clone your fork
3. Commit into your local repo
4. Push to your fork
5. Create pull request from your fork

See details: [The beginner's guide to contributing to a GitHub project](https://akrabat.com/the-beginners-guide-to-contributing-to-a-github-project/) and [Contributing](https://gist.github.com/MarcDiethelm/7303312).

And see [my answer to similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46270523/240564).

Comment: This is the answer, but I would add "2.5. Create branch from current branch"

Answer (score 0):

1. Mark changes

   `git add layouts/community/ergodox/azerty/*`
2. Make a commit with a very short description

   `git commit -m "Short description"`
3. Push your changes to your GitHub project

   `git push`

   Maybe you have to log in now with your credentials.
4. Make a pull request

Go to **your** project page on github.com and click the pull request button.

Answer (score 0):

Git is a distributed version control system, so your branch is just as valid as another branch on someone else's local copy of git.

To do this, you will need to do the following commands:

```
git add -A
```

to add the changes, then

```
git commit -m "Reason for change"
```

to commit the changes locally, then

```
git push
```

to "push" your changes to the remote copy of the branch in which you are working.  If this branch only belongs to you (i.e., not the origin) then you really don't need to do anything else.

If pull requests *are not* enabled for the project, then you simply need to checkout the destination branch, perform the merge, and then push those changes to GitHub.  That is,

```
git checkout <DestinationBranch>
git merge <SourceBranchWithYourChanges>
git push
```

However, if pull requests *are* enabled on the repository, then only certain people will have the ability to merge into the `origin\master` (or whatever the name of the branch is).

To do this, you need to log into GitHub and then follow the instructions that GitHub provided (specified in the link within your question).  This will prompt a user who can merge the request to merge your changes into the appropriate branch for more general consumption.

Answer (score 0):

As you may have read from the page you linked, you need to fork the repo before you can create a pull request to a repo that you don't own. Here is what I would do in your situation

1. Fork the repo on github.com
2. Clone the forked repo to your computer
3. Copy the folders .git and .github in the repo you just downloaded into the repo which you cloned and edited and overwrite the original ones
4. Now, you may add, commit, and push (or perhaps create a new branch, following the official instructions) in the repo where you made your changes.
5. Finally, go to github.com and create a pull request.

Tested and no issue.